# How do I encrypt words by reducing the decimal form of words entered according to the input in C and print it?

Tags: c, pointers, encryption

So I have a question, I was asked to encrypt a word using ASCII, with the following parameters

Input

`12 2`  //16 is the number of words , 2 is the subtraction number for the decimal form of the word

`Good Morning` // the words, spaces are not encrypted

Output

`Gmob Mmrlilg` // only 2 multiply of characters are encrypted

I have tried to make the decimal subtraction program first and not considering the space. But its error on pointer values

I have tried this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int x,y,dec_ofletter;
char a;

char z[100];

char w[100];

char encrypt(int x,int y, char *z){
 int i;
 int h=strlen(z);
 for(i=0;i<h;i++){
  if(i%2==0){
   dec_ofletter=z[i]
   dec_ofletter = dec_ofletter-y;
  }
  z[i]=dec_ofletter;
 }
 return z;
}

int main(void) 
{
 scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
 scanf("%99[^\n]",z);
 a=encrypt(x,y,z);
 printf("%s",a);
 return 0;
}
```

But it getting error. In console it say

```
main.c:16:20: error: indirection requires pointer operand
  ('int' invalid)
  dec_ofletter=*z[i]
               ^~~~~
main.c:19:3: error: indirection requires pointer operand
  ('int' invalid)
*z[i]=dec_ofletter;
^~~~~
```

thanks for your kind help

**update** the pointer problem is solved , but di output is like this

```
12 2 Good Morning  //input
exited, segmentation fault //output
```

Is the logic of my program wrong?

Comment: `z[i]` isn't a *pointer*, it's a *character*.

Comment: @FredLarsonyes but i want to reduce the _char_ value in _decimal_ form then display it as a _string_. Example:
The c decimal is 98, reduced by 2 to 97 which is 'a'. I want to display it again as a _string_.. So what the solution?

Comment: Regardless, you can't dereference a `char`. Assign the char value to an `int` if you like, but don't treat it like a pointer.

Comment: i want to save decimal value in `dec_ofletter` variable and then convert it to char again in `z[i]`

Comment: @FredLarson if i delete the pointer, it show like this. I dont get it. `main.c:16:21: error: subscripted value is not an array,
      pointer, or vector
      dec_ofletter=z[i]
                   ~^~
main.c:19:4: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer,
      or vector
  z[i]=dec_ofletter;
  ~^~`

Comment: Ah, you removed the `* ` where you should not have. `z` must be a pointer within the `encrypt()` function, but `z[i]` will not be a pointer.

Comment: <OT> but eventually relevant, I doni't think you want to loop `i <= h`. That last iteration will be the `NUL` terminator.. you're not going to want to shift that character or it will blow up your string.

Comment: @yano: Correct, but `i` must start at `0` as well or it will not encrypt the first character.

Comment: @FredLarson based on his sample input/output, doesn't look like OP wants to shift the first letter.

Comment: @yano what is the correct program flow for you? I was confused when exchanging the value

Comment: @Johnstone88 what is `x`? It's unused in `encrypt`. I think you're segfaulting now b/c of my first comment. `strlen("Good Morning")` is 12, so your `for` loop is getting to that 13th character (the `NUL` terminator at `z[12]`), subtracting 2 from it, which destroys the terminator. Then you try to print, `printf` happily goes along looking for the next `NUL` terminator, and it runs into memory it doesn't own before that happens, and you bomb out. Try changing that to `i<h`

Comment: you're also using the wrong format specifier to print a `char`. `a` is a `char`, use `%c` to print that, `%s` expects a string. But I suspect you want `printf("%s", z);` there.

Comment: the return type of `encrypt` is a `char`, yet you return a `char*`.

Comment: @yano i ve changed it to this `
`char encrypt(int x,int y, char *z){
  int i;
  int h=strlen(z);
  for(i=0;i<h;i++){

    if(i%2==0){
      dec_ofletter=z[i];
       dec_ofletter = dec_ofletter-y;
    }
  z[i]=dec_ofletter;
  }
  return z;
}`

Comment: @yanoactually x to limit the number of strings entered. But I haven't considered it because I focused on encryption first.

Comment: Yes I want to print string, in my previous program I can print _char_ with `%s` too. it working

Comment: using the wrong format specifier is undefined behavior, it's working by chance. It may not work 5 min from now, or if you change the compiler flags, or when the TA compiles and runs your code. `%s` expected a _string_, which is a character array terminated with `'\0'`, `%c` expects simply a single character. Pay attention to the warnings of your compiler, `encrypt` is still returning the wrong type.

Comment: Your debugger should stop on the line of the segfault, otherwise, consider adding some debug printing to your loop.  I can see a segfault if the value of `i` were greater than the size of `z` or if your printf() of a string while using a char happened to read into bad memory trying to find a NUL terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Have added a `flag` to ensure purposed entry into the correct conditional.

The logic employed is

1 Start the counter `int i` at one.

- since you are attempting to replace every second non-space character
  from the array.
- And to control the flow of the conditionals that follow.

2.Check if the character is space,

- `if` yes check if the counter is even or odd.
- If even or odd set the flag accordingly and `continue`(since spaces are not encrypted).

3.The following `ifs` update the array based on odd/even positions and the flag which was in the first `if`.

In addition,

- am returning the character pointer (char *) received in the `encrypt` function
  back to `main`.
- Have removed the `global` variable `dec_ofletter` since it is not
  required in operations.

The code should, hopefully, be able to handle leading and multiple spaces in between words.

Putting it together, this is the code......

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int x,y;
char a;

char z[100];

char w[100];

char * encrypt(int x,int y, char *z){
  int i;
  int flag = 1;//set flag at beginning 
  int h=strlen(z);
  for(i = 1;i<h;i++){//set counter at 1
    if(z[i] == ' '){   //If space
      if(i % 2 == 1){  //counter is odd
        flag = 1;      //set flag
        continue;
      }
      if(i % 2 == 0){//If even 
        flag = 0;    //clear flag
        continue;
      }
    }
  if(i%2==1 && flag == 1)//select odd based on flag
  z[i] = z[i] - y;//update array
  if(i%2 == 0 && flag == 0)//select even based on flag
    z[i] = z[i] - y;//update array

  }
 return z;
}   

int main(void) 
{
  scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
  getchar();
  scanf("%99[^\n]",z);
  encrypt(x,y,z);
  printf("%s",z);
  return 0;
}
```